# Dirac notation and matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, notation

If I have an operator $A$ whose elements can be written as $<\phi_{m}|A|\phi_{n}>$ does this mean that I can write the operator $A$ as:

$$A=|\phi_{m}><\phi_{m}|A|\phi_{n}><\phi_{n}|$$

Answer (score 3):

You can use the resolution of identity to obtain the operator expressed with respect to your basis. Given a discrete orthonormal basis $B=\{|\phi_n\rangle\}$, $\langle \phi_m|\phi_n\rangle = \delta_{nm}$ such that $\sum_n |\phi_n\rangle \langle \phi_n|=\hat 1$, an operator can be written as
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat A &= \hat 1 \hat A\hat 1 \\
\hat A&= \left(\sum_m |\phi_m\rangle \langle \phi_m|\right)\hat A \left(\sum_n |\phi_n\rangle \langle \phi_n|\right) \\
\hat A&= \sum_m \sum_n|\phi_m\rangle \langle \phi_m|\hat A  |\phi_n\rangle \langle \phi_n| \\
\end{aligned}$$

The term  $\langle \phi_m| \hat A |\phi_n \rangle$ is also known as matrix element of operator $\hat A$ since we can represent the operator with respect to the basis $B=\{|\phi_n\rangle\}$ using the matrix $\mathbf A$ with matrix elements $A_{mn} = \langle \phi_m| \hat A |\phi_n \rangle$.

What you have written down is just one term from the whole double sum that makes up the complete operator. It would only be correct if all matrix elements vanish except $A_{mn}$, but that is not the general case.

Note that the same approach works when you have a continuous or mixed spectrum, just plug in the according resolution of identity to obtain the operator representation.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. you have to integrate those by all m and n. And $|\phi_{m}>$ have to span entire space. If m and n are discrete, substitute the integration operator to sigma operator.
$$A=\int dm \int dn|\phi_{m}><\phi_{m}|A|\phi_{n}><\phi_{n}|$$

Comment: Consider to use \langle and \rangle instead of < and >.